# Rails ajax with POST function: why template missing?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm completing an avatar upload and crop using ajax submit.

I'm sending via ajax the base64 image and then I convert my image for carrierwave.

Everything works fine, except for the ajax response: Template missing.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/profile/update_avatar",
  data: { image: canvas.toDataURL() }
})
.done(function(data) {

  // You can pull the image URL using data.url, e.g.:
  $('.user-image').html('<img src="'+data.url+'" />');

});
```

And this is my controller:

```
def update_avatar
respond_to do |format|
  if current_user.update_cropped_avatar(params[:image])
    format.js
    format.html { render :nothing => true, :notice => 'Update SUCCESSFUL!' }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.json { render :json => current_user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I don't need to render template... but the error is:

```
Missing template profiles/update_avatar, application/update_avatar with {:locale=>[:it], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem will be your use of:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
```

I know you sent JSON to Rails, but it seems you're only processing a standard [`script` dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) when your avatar is sent correctly. Your use of `format.js` basically causes rails to look for `action_name.js.erb` in your `views` folder - hence your template error

There are numerous ways to fix this, including:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render nothing: true }
```

---

**Fix**

After talking with Roberto in chat, here's what worked for him:

```
def update_avatar 
    respond_to do |format| 
        if current_user.update_cropped_avatar(params[:image]) 
            format.json { render :json => current_user.profile.avatar_url, :status => 200 } 
            format.html { render :nothing => true, :notice => 'Update SUCCESSFUL!' } 
        else 
            format.html { render :action => "edit" } 
            format.json { render :json => current_user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity } 
        end 
    end 
end
```

Comment: in my js I have also $('.user-image').html('<img src="'+data.url+'" />') to update the image. How can I merge this with your code?

Comment: With my code, you'll still get back the `image` object in the `data` var in JS. What you'll have to determine is what's inside the `data` object, and then call the `url` --> if you could put `console.log(data)` in your `done` JS, and let me know the results, I'll be able to help you better

Comment: I'm trying but in your code there is something I don't understand, where I have to place respond_to :html, :json ? At the top of my controller?
And you have something wrong with nesting, I cannot figure why you have three end.

Comment: Hey Roberto, sorry about that - removed the incorrect `end`. The respond_to goes at the top of your controller - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

Comment: there is also en error in status, : instead of = :)

Comment: undefined method `model_name' for AvatarUploader:Class in respond_with... I'm using Carrierwave. I think I must respond with HTML.

Comment: Everythink is fine, but I can't manage the answer. The image is uploaded but I need to return my image to the browser...

Answer (score 3):

In your controller action method you wrote `format.js` Which is the reason of this error.

Change it to `format.json { render :json => true }`, or in your views you can create a file called: `profiles/update_avatar.js`.

So your controller action should look like this:

```
def update_avatar
respond_to do |format|
  if current_user.update_cropped_avatar(params[:image])
    format.json { render :json => true }   #<-------Change here
    format.html { render :nothing => true, :notice => 'Update SUCCESSFUL!' }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.json { render :json => current_user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```